# Class 'Paypal' not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Paypal;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{


private $_apiContext;
public function __construct() {
    $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
        config('services.paypal.client_id'),
        config('services.paypal.secret'));

    $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ));
}
```

I'm getting an error that
Class 'Paypal' not found
in SubscriptionController.php line 17
But my IDE shows that it's there, I even used it in another project and its working fine.

In my app.php I have: 
        'Paypal' => 'Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal',
So it should be good.

Why do I get that error?

Comment: If you run a `composer dump-autoload`, does that help? Sometimes the autoload file doesn't load properly and you class can't be found.

Comment: @Loek, i did a composer autoload 2 times so far, but still the same error

Comment: Hmm weird. Have seen more issues with PayPal facades on SO lately, but no one really comes up with an answer other than dump the autoloader.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`

Comment: @Paras thanks for the tip, bit im still getting that error. The thing that bugs me the most, I have another project where its working fine and I have checked if something is not the same, but cant find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php artisan config:cache` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your Laravel project root to install Paypal `composer require netshell/paypal dev-master`

After that, add the service provider to `app/config/app.php` in the `providers` array.

```
'providers' => [
// ...
    'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider',
]
```

At the end, add an alias to `app/config/app.php` in the `aliases` array

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
    'Paypal' => 'Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal',
]
```

After that you should be able to use `Paypal`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `use Paypal;` line. If you are defining an alias in app.php, I don't think you need a `use` statement for it - that has been my experience when defining my own aliases.

You can also try defining your alias with a different syntax to see if it helps:

```
'Paypal' => Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal::class
```

(notice there are no quotes on the value as it is a reference to a class).

Comment: Nope you do need the use statement with facades/aliases. Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#how-facades-work Notice the `use Cache;`

Comment: @Paras Thanks, interesting. I think in my own experience it worked because I am not actually aliasing a true Facade in my usage, just a custom class with static methods. I suppose if `Paypal::class` implements a Facade, the `use` might indeed be needed as per the docs.

Comment: I have tried it with 'Paypal' => Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal::class but i'm getting same error. if i add 
use Netshell\Paypal\Paypal; the error changes to Non-static method Netshell\Paypal\Paypal::apiContext() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing `use \Paypal;`?